# Find material for improvement in Microsoft BI

Tags: ssas, ssis, business-intelligence, ssrs

Which websites, books etc. can you recommend me to improve my basic knowledge in Microsoft Business Intelligence 2008, SSAS, SSIS and SSRS?

Please remember that I'm a newbie in technical BI tool.

If possible, it would be great to retrieve any material for task work that would be similiar as doing lab task at university.

// Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book ["The Data Warehouse Toolkit" by Kimball](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471200247) is a must for any fledging BI developer, IMO.

Comment: Name of a book?

Comment: yes, added author to the post

Answer (score 4):

I'd say less as an initial starting point but more as an indispensable resource, there are some great blogs out there:

[SSIS Junkie/Jamie Thomson](https://web.archive.org/web/20200711091058/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/)

[SSIS Team Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS)

Answer (score 3):

The [Microsoft Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/sql+server+2008+r2) site is a great place to start.